# KVM - List snapshots in order of creation

Tags: kvm, snapshot, virsh

I've only just realized that **KVM snapshots default to being listed in alphabetical order, rather than chronological**. This can be confusing if you sometimes use the command `virsh snapshot-create-as $ID "$NAME"` in order to create snapshots. This can result in output similar to below which is hard to find the latest snapshot from (especially if it's a long list):

```
 Name                 Creation Time             State                                                          │
------------------------------------------------------------                                                   │
 1474043443           2016-09-16 17:30:43 +0100 running                                                        │
 1476197777           2016-10-11 15:56:17 +0100 running                                                        │
 1476721835           2016-10-17 17:30:35 +0100 running                                                        │
 1476953503           2016-10-20 09:51:43 +0100 running                                                        │
 consolidated         2016-09-25 08:06:27 +0100 running                                                        │
 just installed mysql 5.6 2016-09-16 10:19:46 +0100 running                                                    │
 updated vars         2016-09-24 04:02:24 +0100 running
```

**Is there a way to list the snapshots in chronological order?** That way I can (or a script can be programmed to) just read the name from either the top or bottom of the list to grab the latest one. If not, is there a place I can raise this to put in a request for a `--chronological` parameter?

After reading the [Redhat documentation on managing snapshots](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Virtualization_Deployment_and_Administration_Guide/sect-Managing_guest_virtual_machines_with_virsh-Managing_snapshots.html), I have found the `--tree` and `--leaves` options which are helpful to me in this specific case as `--leaves` gives me the latest snapshot which is what I'm after, but would probably list several if there were several "paths". I'm not sure if the last line in a `--tree` option would always give me the latest snapshot. It may depend on the alphabetical names of the "branches" when the splits were made. --current` does not work for me as I get the following error message:

```
error: Domain snapshot not found: the domain does not have a current snapshot
```

I am guessing this is because the virtual machine had its snapshot taken whilst it was running, and it is also currently still running.

I guess one could easily write a script to parse the `Creation Time` in the output to automatically fetch the name of the latest snapshot but it would be nice if this was somehow built-in.

Comment: Make sure your snapshot name starts with the unix timestamp then pipe the output to `sort -n` (you can use the `--name` parameter to only output names)